# Triggering scheduled emails or SMS on LAMP

Tags: php, cron, lamp

I’m working on a project using the LAMP stack. I need to send emails and SMS at certain times. “Certain times” is based on results of sql queries. What would be some ways to achieve this?

I am thinking of a cron job that invokes a php file which in turn runs the queries and based on the results, triggers the email and sms APIs as needed.

Is this a reasonable approach or overkill ? Are there alternative/simpler/better/more efficient ways to perform such tasks?

Comment: cron is just fine and exactly the right tool for the job. Not sure why you think it's overkill. You use cron to run a small program, written in PHP or whatever else, periodically so it can do whatever checks and actions it needs to make.

Comment: @deceze not sure.. I guess just the thought of relying on a separate os level module. Like.. what if the job stops working and the monitoring overheads that I would need to implement. Those were the kind of things running in my head. I’m a relative beginner and just want to make sure the high level approach is right.

Comment: cron is crucial for many system-level tasks, if *it* stops working you have bigger issues. You just need to set up your task correctly once, then it should continue to work unless you screw it up; that generally goes for anything, so cron isn't special in that regard.